# What exactly does "るぅ" mean?

Tags: usage, nuances

Good afternoon all,

Sometimes I see that people like to "curl" the last mora of a verb, for example:

> 瑞生: ああそれから、亜湖にも特別ボーナスだ。
>
> 亜湖: えっ。
>
> 瑞生: ジャーン！
>
> 亜湖: 何それ？
>
> 瑞生: かわいいだろう？
>
> 瑞生: おいおいおい、ほら、ちょっと、当ててみろよ。
>
> 亜湖: 何？
>
> 瑞生: ほらほらほら…。
>
> 瑞生: わあ、似合ってるぅ！

([Youtube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=B2CS7yKO8T8#t=551s))

I was wondering what exactly does it mean to curl the "る" sound of the verb, and in what situations do we do that?

Comment: It's just 「似合ってる～」（=似合っている）, with the final sound prolonged... like you say 'Aaand...'/'Veeery'/'Ahhhh'...

Comment: @Chocolate Btw I was wondering what's the various purposes of the elongated "る".. can it be used to make *fun* of the other party?

Comment: No I don't think it expresses contempt or hatred etc. In this case わあ、似合ってるぅ！ means 'Wow, it looks good on you~~!'. I think it's normally added to show emphasis or exclamation.

Comment: @Chocolate Cool, thanks for the clarification =)

Comment: @Pacerier It definitely can be used to make fun of the other person. However this is normally targeted at English speakers attempting to speak Japanese since beginners normally extend the u sounds more than they should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes it feminine and cute. It may imply that the pronunciation is done with [アヒル口](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%82%A2%E3%83%92%E3%83%AB%E5%8F%A3&hl=en&prmd=imvnsl&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=6piCT_-gNuXq0gHo4oCbCA&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CBcQ_AUoAQ&biw=666&bih=662) (duck mouth).

Comment: Uh btw I was thinking in the context of the video, what *message* is the father trying to convey when he says "似合ってるぅ" ?

Comment: @Pacerier, Ew, "father"?

Comment: @Chocolate Erm ya the father uses the "る～", @ http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=B2CS7yKO8T8#t=551s

Comment: In English we typically say "duckface", as one word.